# Index Match with multiple criteria needs to return the closest value that is less than or equal to search value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

Right now the issue is that the formula returns the closest value regardless of whether its a high or lower value. I need to only Accept Lower than values.

```
{=INDEX($AO$2:$AO$5000,MATCH(SMALL(IF($AN$2:$AN$5000=A2,ABS($AO$2:$AO$5000-F2)),1),IF($AN$2:$AN$5000=A2,ABS($AO$2:$AO$5000-F2)),0))}
```

For reference:

AO is a Dollar amount

AN is a Date

A is Date

F is a Dollar amount

We are looking to match the Dates in AN to A and then find the closest Dollar amount in AO that is less than or equaled to F.  There can be multiple instances on the same day with varying dollar amounts. we just need the closest one without going over what's in F to be returned. This does not have to be an index match formula if you can think of a better way to do it but I'm pretty positive it has to be an array formula as it must look at all of the values to  make the correct decision.

Comment: What else have you tried, and what has happened?  Where is the example of your data and desired output?  See SO Help for [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make it easier for us to help you by providing something we can copy/paste into an worksheet; or an actual data sample that you have uploaded to a file sharing site.

Comment: Without looking at your data, it is hard to help.  But if you have your data sorted, you can simply use `VLOOKUP` with 1 (or `TRUE`) in the `Range_lookup` field (ie. `=VLOOKUP(A2,$AN$2:$AN$5000,3,1)`).  If not, post some sample data and we can help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,($AO$2:$AO$5000)/(($AN$2:$AN$5000=A2)*(($AO$2:$AO$5000)<=F2)),1)
```

the part after the / will evaluate to 0 if either is false.  this causes an error which aggregate will ignore due to the 6.  14 tells aggregate to sort the results from largest to smallest.  1 tells aggregate to return the 1st largest value that is less than or equal to F2.

Comment: nailed it! and what a novel approach I have not played around much with the aggregate function. Will do so more from now on. Thank you good sir.